# Не работает git push через IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, github, git-push

Я пытаюсь пушить в репозиторий общества, в котором у меня есть права. Если я через консоль (винды) ввожу просто `git push`, то всё работает. Но если я пушу через PyCharm/IDEA/AndroidStudio и т. д. и т. п., то они юзают команду `git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/main:main`, и мне вылетает:

```
remote: Permission to GigaChatTeam/RTCD.git denied to mister-proger.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/GigaChatTeam/RTCD.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: А в консоли та длинная строка работает?  Если нет, то найдите при добавлении какого аргумента она перестаёт работать.